# Need to convert the field to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Asp.Net MVC Core3.1 :First code : i have two field "shift_from" and "shift_to" formating is like this "2020-01-01 14:22:00.000" type is datetime and i did this code in index.cshtml :

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shiftId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shif_title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.short_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_from)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_to)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_hours)
            </td>


        </tr>
    }
```

I have error :" There is wrong in input" in load page and i think this error is related to must convert this line and how :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_to)
```

Also i tried this and nothing working :

```
@Convert.ToString(string.Format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", item.shift_from))
```

This code too is input how to make it to accept string ?

```
     ` <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="shift_to" class="control-label"></label>
            <input class="shift_to" asp-for="shift_to" type="datetime-local"   />
            <span asp-validation-for="shift_to" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div> `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced   `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_from)` with : `@Convert.ToString(item.shift_from)`

Comment: I think is more wise to use display format instead of convert the value in the view

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [`DisplayFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute in your model property, like:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```

Comment: And if i want too convert this how : <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="shift_to" class="control-label"></label>
                <input class="shift_to" asp-for="shift_to" type="datetime-local"   />
                <span asp-validation-for="shift_to" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

Comment: You want to display it as input?

Comment: Yes i want to display it as input and above code appear error to me .

Comment: You can use EditorFor and ApplyFormatInEditMode = true property on the previous attribute

Comment: Editor not appearing i think is a bug in my end

Comment: I update the post if you could see the issue i appreciate your help .

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.shift_from.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
```

Comment: I update the question in last section how can i solve it ? and thanks